# how to split the spooling into smaller csv files

Tags: shell, sql

I am using a shell script like the following to spool two columns(fields) of a particular table into a csv file as follow:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

FILE="emp.csv"

sqlplus -s scott/tiger@XE  <<EOF

SET PAGESIZE 50000
SET COLSEP ","
SET LINESIZE 200
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT name,city FROM EMP;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

But the resulting csv file is becoming too large for my editor to open. Is there any way by which I can split the records into multiple csv files which are smaller and can be opened ? Can I use some counter such that when it exceeds a particular value the data is spooled to another file ?

Comment: use another editor to open the big file

Comment: can you pipe the output through the `split` command?

Answer (score 2):

```
cat emp.csv | split -l 6000
```

will create a bunch of little files: in this case 6000 lines long.  The default is `xaa`, `xab`, and so on but you can change that: see the man page for `split`.